# $_SESSION variables not carried over on HTTPS

Tags: php, https, session-variables

I am developing a site on my localhost, where everything works fine, but now that the site is uploaded to the HTTPS side of our ***inserted* ONLINE */inserted*** server, the `$_SESSION` variables don't get carried over from the login.php to the index.php page. Both are located on HTTPS, the process never goes out of HTTPS. As I said, everything worked fine on my localhost.

My localhost's PHP is version 5.3.2 and the HTTPS server is 5.2.6. The only difference in settings I can identify regarding sessions is `session.use_only_cookies` is `On` on my localhost and `Off` on the HTTPS server.

Can anyone please shed some light as to why the session variables are not transferred? PS. I do have `session_start();` in both login.php and index.php.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the same domain on both localhost and the remote server?

Comment: Are both login.php and index.php access though https? Are they both on the same domain?

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm interested to know what the problem was...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the session cookie is carried over between the HTTP and HTTPS requests? And that the same session token is present on both sides?

If the cookie established via the HTTPS page is marked as "secure only", it will not be transmitted to non-SSL pages, so you'd get a brand new empty session on the non-secure pages, which would give you the symptoms of "missing" session variables. They're not really missing, just in some other session which isn't active now.

Comment: The `$_SESSION` variables are transferred only within HTTPS, the process never ventures into plain HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that can go wrong.

Make sure both login.php and index.php are accessed through https. `session.cookie_secure` defaults to off, but you never know.

Also make sure they are they both on the same domain. Cookies are set per-domain.

Maybe there is some oddball cookie setting? You can view the current session cookie settings with: `session_get_cookie_params()`
You can also verify how the cookie is being set in your browser (if at all), for Opera you can right-click in the page, select "edit site preferences", and use the "Cookie" tab. Don't know about other browsers from the top of my head ...

Another possibility is a borked `session.save_path`, run `session_save_path()` without any arguments to get the current session_save_path, make sure the user running PHP (typically but not necessarily the same user running the webserver) can write to this directory.

Comment: The variables containing Boolean values get set and are carried over, but the ones containing anything else, integer or String, are not carried over between the two pages.

Comment: So, should `session.cookie_secure` be `On` or `Off`?

Comment: If you use https exclusively (As you do) it doesn't matter, I just added that for the people ending up here through google.

Comment: How odd! You're not using some sort of custom session save handler?

Comment: Nope, I am not, I'm busy trying the variables & seeing where precisely it disappears.

Comment: I have determined that the `$_SESSION['user_id']` gets set on login.php and in the redirection via `header()`, it gets set to 0. The Boolean values however get transferred over, or so it seems.

Comment: Apparently, this server I'm using doesn't allow you to plainly use `$_SESSION['user_id']`, you should get your own variable name. I didn't know it was reserved, is it?

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide a link to `phpinfo()` and to a simple script which calls `session_start()` and sets some `$_SESSION` var?